# Product Delete create re- indexer issue in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, database, catalog, reindex, delete

When I delete a product in Magento 2 using CSV import or through admin then after I re-index then category product and product category having indexer issue like

> `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0-82-1-9.0000' for key 'PRIMARY', the query was: INSERT INTO catalog_product_index_eav_decimal_idx`.

when I check-in database table, find a product is deleted only from a catalog_product_entity table.

But in the remaining table that entity id are still present like in `catalog_product_entity_decimal`, `catalog_product_entity_int`, `catalog_product_entity_text` etc.